# Sharepoint 2013 - Search files into File Share (content source) with filtering by folders

Tags: 2013, search, filter, refiner

I crawled content that is on stored on file server (File Share - content source in SharePoint Server) and i get the results in SharePoint search. Everything is fine but i need to have some kind of refiner (i tried many of them but none is working in the way that i need, or it is not working at all) that will have opportunity to choose the folder in which i want to search for some file. Could you give me some suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check [Search Query Tool](https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/) out... There you can see all properties of the returning results.

You can refine by path or something like that, to narrow down your results..

Not tested Query, but something like that should to it...

```
Path<>"\\fileserver\folderA"
```

Remember: If you want to refine or sort some properties, you have to configure the Managed Properties in the SSA. (search schema).

Comment: i tried like this "{SearchBoxQuery} and ContentSource:FileServer and Path:"file://fileserver/.../{QueryString.MyParameter1}/" " so it is working. I am getting one parameter from url which i set from my custom navigation links. The sign <> that you put is not for equal but for different from... However thanks for your help, Search Query Tool helped me a lot.